# Чем дополнить имеющийся скрипт вызова блока по клику, что бы под ним запретить скролл?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>      
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.hasClass('menu-item-search') || $target.hasClass('glyphicon-remove')) {
      $('.form-container').fadeIn(150);
    } else if(!$target.parents("div").hasClass('form-container')) {
      $('.form-container').fadeOut(150)
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Запретить скролл у чего, у блока с классом "form-container"?

Comment: А точно..В html, body, которые окажутся позади открывшегося .form-container